# What is the difference between supposed to and meant to

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms, parallelism

> It is because it was always meant to be so.
>
> It is because it was always supposed to be so.

What is the difference between *meant* and *supposed*? There must be more but all I can deconstruct is that *meant* is a verb dependent upon the unquestionable intention of the subjects purpose and *supposed* is a description of intention realized without as much value for outcome given to absolute per determination. Can anyone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 3):

As an aside, I would start both sentences with *It is **so**,*.

Something that is *meant* to be a certain way certainly indicates a *purpose* on the side of an agent that supposedly *made* it so.

Something that is *supposed* to be a certain way indicates a certain *expectation* from the side of the observer.

> His artwork is *meant* to be shocking.

The artist has the *intention* to shock.

> His artwork is *supposed* to be shocking.

Well, I heard that he meant to shock people with his art, but honestly, I do not find it shocking at all.

However, *supposed* can also mean that something is expected to be a certain way *because it is the proper way for things to be*:

> The bus was *supposed* to arrive at three.
>   Are those holes *supposed* to be there?
>   Aren't you *supposed* to be at school?

*Sometimes* we can actually substitute *meant* in those cases:

> Did you *mean* to make those holes there? (Or was it an accident?)

However, more commonly you would use *should* as a substitution:

> The bus *should* have arrived at three.
>   *Should* those holes be there?
>   *Shouldn't* you be at school?

In your example, I would use *meant*.

Using the first sense of *supposed*, *it was always supposed to be so* seems like a rather non-committal *ah well, we always expected it to be so*, which can hardly be an explanation of *why* it is so.

Using the second meaning, *it was always supposed to be so* seems to indicate that *in the past* this was how things should be - but no longer. So again, it doesn't explain why it *is* so at present. If you change it to the present tense, you can get the desired meaning:

> It is so, because it is supposed to be so.